# Как вывести текст и результат выполения функции одновременно?

Tags: функции, bash, shell

Нужно вывести текст и результат выполнения функции, которые извлекается из файла, одновременно. Делаю по варианту 1, выводится как текст "a fun_b". функция не выполнилась. Делаю по варианту 2, выводится как результат команды и соответственно команду "а" не находит "./test.sh: line 13: a: command not found". Нужный результат "a b". Как сделать?

```
#!/bin/bash

fun_b ()
{
    echo "b"
}

cat ./1.txt

text="$(cat ./1.txt)"

echo "$text" # 1 вариант. как текст
echo "$($text)" # 2 вариант. как команда

# нужно чтобы вывод был такой "a b"
```

Вывод

```
a fun_b
a fun_b
./test.sh: line 13: a: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите преобразовать текстовую строку в команду то для этого можно использовать `eval`

```
$ eval 'echo Текст'
Текст
```

но для корректной работы `eval` нужно чтобы весь передаваемый текст был валидным.

В вашем же примере выдаёт ошибку так как `а` это неизвестная команда, в **bash** *первое слово* означает команду, а последующие слова это параметры данной команды. То есть, если смотреть второй вариант

```
fun_b(){ echo "b";}
text="a fun_b"
eval $text
```

выходит что нужно выполнить команду/функцию `a` и передать ей один параметр `fun_b`, что естественно вызовет ошибку, так как `a` это неизвестная команда/функция.

чтобы получить в ответ строку `a b`, где `a` это текст, а `b` результат работы функции `fun_b` нужно будет сравнить каждое слово и если оно соответствует указанной функции то выполнить эту функцию и вернуть результат, в противном случае просто вывести слово. В простом варианте это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
fun_b(){ echo "b";}
text="a fun_b"
z=($text) # arrays
for i in "${z[@]}"; do
    [[ "$i" == "fun_b" ]] && fun_b || echo -n "$i "
done
```